# Proving that a series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If I can show that $\displaystyle \sum_{k\geq1}a_k^2<\infty$, then is this an acceptable proof that $\displaystyle \sum_{k\geq1}a_k^2$ is convergent?

Comment: That is not enough. Use the definition of convergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By defintion, $\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}b_k$ converges if and only if the sequence of partial sums converges, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n = L$, where $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n b_k$.

If $b_k\geq 0$ for all $k$, then the sequence of partial sums is monotone, $s_1\leq s_2\leq s_3\leq\cdots$.

A monotone sequence converges if and only if it is bounded. Therefore, for a series of nonnegative terms $b_k\geq 0$, we have that $\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}b_k$ converges if and only if the sequence $s_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^nb_k$ is bounded, if and only if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n\lt\infty$, if and only if $\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}b_k\lt \infty$.

That is: for a series with nonnegative terms, the only two possibilities are that the series is bounded and converges, or that the series diverges to $\infty$.

If $b_k = a_k^2$ and all $a_k$ are real, then $b_k\geq 0$, so the observation above applies: if you can prove that the partial sums are bounded (which is the only reasonable meaning of $\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}a_k^2\lt \infty$), then the series necessarily converges.

Answer (score 2):

It is true if $a_k$ is eventually nonnegative (there exists $K$ such that $a_k \geq  0$ for $k > K$.

The series $\sum_{k \geq 1} (-1)$ satisfy your inequality and diverges.

If it is the case where $a_k \geq 0$ then the sequence $S_n := \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} a_k$ is eventually increasing and bounded. Hence it converges.

---

For the edited question, yes, it is true. Your inequality is now *equivalent* to the convergence of the series. The reason is as above. The sequence of partial sums of your series is monotone increasing and bounded, hence converges.

Comment: I think you mean $a_k > 0$ for some non-finite subsequence of $a$.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Edited the answer. It is quite similar as to the previous question.